# How to change url pagination in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.1

I want my url to change from this
`/examinations/getchoices/page:2`

to this
`/examinations/getchoices/item/2`

I wonder how to do this. I've already tried changing in the routes.php. I've tried the tutorial in [this site](http://www.sakic.net/blog/changing-cakephp-pagination-urls/). The page content doesn't change when I click prev or next links.

This is what i got in the url
`/examinations/getchoices/ 2/ 2`

My version of cake is 2.1.

Your help will be much appreciated. I've been stuck with this for 2 days already. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can define custom routes.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html

e.g.

```
Router::connect(
  ' /examinations/getchoices/item/:number',
  array('controller' => 'examinations', 'action' => 'getchoices'),
  array('pass' => array('number'))
);
```

let me know if i can assist you more

Comment: And one more example here: http://www.sakic.net/blog/changing-cakephp-pagination-urls/